# Безопасность API аутентификации через JWT

Tags: api, безопасность, spa, аутентификация

Всем привет. Смотрю сейчас различные библиотеки по аутентификации через токены (oauth2/jwt-auth и т.д.), не понимаю одного: насколько я знаю, все данные, связанные с безопасностью, лучше хранить в httpOnly куках. Вышеперечисленные пакеты в ответе отдают `access token` и `refresh token`. Через js вставить httpOnly cookie не получится. Каким образом нужно хранить токен доступа на стороне клиента?

Приложение делается без серверной части, то есть полностью без сохранения состояния (stateless). В наличии только API от backend'a и приложение на Vue.js. Как быть, где хранить токены?

Comment: В localStorage.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а что касаемо безопасности? Это самое лучшее решение на данный момент? Получается, что любой злоумышленник, который получит доступ к localStorage, получает доступ к личному кабинету юзера?

Comment: Его нужно еще сначала получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вы пишите: *"приложение делается без серверной части"*. Это автоматически означает, что никакие httpOnly куки вам не доступны независимо от того используете ли вы токены. Хранить же токены надо там, где получается - в localStorage или подобных местах.

Теперь про безопасность. Безопасность токенов реализуется через ограничение области действия и времени жизни. Эти ограничения работают совместно: токены с широкой областью действия обычно короткоживущие, а с узкой могут жить долго.

С вашей стороны нужно запрашивать правильные области (scope) при получении токена. К примеру, запрашивать какой-нибудь скоуп вроде users.profile:write и сохранять такой токен - не лучшая идея, а вот im:read можно сохранять надолго (для примера я взял области действия токена из [API Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth-scopes))

Если же вам в приложении понадобится изменить настройки безопасности аккаунта через API - то токен для этой операции лучше запросить отдельно. И забыть сразу после операции никуда его не сохраняя.

Comment: Павел, большое спасибо! Теперь понял, как именно это делается :)